# Sprite Kit restitution set to 1 not realistic

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to SpriteKit I was discovering things on it.

I set restitution to 1.0 in hope to when my ball reaches ground it get back to it's previous location but this didn't happen.

What's the reason behind it?
(If its duplicate question I couldn't find the other one so I excuse if it is)

For the code you may consider below code in `didMove()` function.

```
    scene?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 400)
    ball.fillColor = .red
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1;
    addChild(ball)
```

Comment: Please add code and/or image example of your problem. And how to reproduce it.

Comment: is affectedByGravity set to true for the ball?

Comment: Yes, clearly gravity is a problem.  You are never going to get a ball to bounce up to its original spot because even though you get an equal and opposite reaction when you hit the ground, gravity is still pulling the ball down.  You would have to some how have a greater force going back up then you would going down.

Comment: hmmm if only there was a way to turn off " affectedByGravity" and apply "affectedByGravityReverse" on the ball in "override func didSimulatePhysics()". Hmmm maybe there is.... you'd need yo do some math though.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That's not physics when we say restitution is 1 energy is not wasted then all gravity does is decreasing it's velocity (Kinetic Energy) and change it to Potential energy.

Comment: @hoboBob So what's the meaning of restitution in SpriteKit ?

Comment: @Maetschl I did more clarification.

Comment: @Parsa no one is here to argue. Restitution is a value that determines how much of the resultant force from the physics calculation is applied to an object once the physics world determines a collision has occurred. 1 (all of the force), 0 (None). The math behind it pretty sound (some may say there is an inaccuracy (some magic number) in my own experience 've never come across it. Brush up on vector math and test it yourself.

Comment: @hoboBob Yes, definitely. So you say that air resistant is under action too (the same as real life) ?
If it is like that then how it is controlled in the SpriteKit ? Can you send me a link or sth ?

Comment: @Parsa. For air/fluid resistance you are given the property physicsBody?.linearDampening to play with. It operates similar to .restitution, 0(none) 1(max). How is it controlled by sprite Kit? well thats a huge question and completely different to  the OP.  code.https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsworld

Comment: @hoboBob I'm completely confused by "Brush up on vector math and test it yourself". I just want to get the exact concept of restitution in SpriteKit and thanks for your link.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520447-restitution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210881/discussion-between-parsa-noori-and-hobobob).

Comment: @hoboBob I read that before creating this post and that was in conflict with the actual behavior of code. While it says it's like physics restitution but it acts like some thing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind that was air friction which is set by default in SpriteKit's physic world.

I should have add `ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0` and it would bounce until the end of world